# is it a normal to have load average upper than 1?

Tags: redhat, top, load-average

On 7.9 redhat os.

I was told by our admin server that load average (can be seen using top) of my server should not be upper than 1.

but our 3 servers have a load balancing that is equal to 7.78, or even 11 on another server.

each time the process usage is low (around 20%). we have 32 cores.

is it really a problem to have load average upper than 1 ? if not what would be the value to monitor ?

Comment: Servers low end? Like single core VPN? Because when you read the manual what the load average means, then having a load average AROUND the number of cores is not really a sign of overloading. I find the number fundamentally flawed - likely still the best you can do - because it just indicates the number of waiting processes, regardless of waiting time, and in a many core server they can get eaten FAST.

Comment: @TomTom LA is not the number of waiting processes. It is the number of processes which are either running or ready to run or in an uninterruptible state.